# How to convert strong html elements into span elements iText 7?

Tags: c#, itext7

this is my code but I don't know if it's ok. Help

```
public class CustomTagWorker : DefaultTagWorkerFactory
        {
 public override ITagWorker GetCustomTagWorker(IElementNode tag, ProcessorContext context)
            {     
              
                    if (tag.Name().Equals(TagConstants.STRONG, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        
                        return new CustomSpanTagWorker(tag, context);
                        
                    }
                


                return null;
            }
}
```

```
private class CustomSpanTagWorker : SpanTagWorker
        {
            public CustomSpanTagWorker(IElementNode element, ProcessorContext context) : base(element, context)
            {
            }

            public override void ProcessEnd(IElementNode element, ProcessorContext context)
            {
                base.ProcessEnd(element, context);
               
                IList elementResult = GetAllElements();                              

                if (elementResult != null )
                {
                    foreach (iText.Layout.IPropertyContainer item in elementResult)
                    {
                        
                        base.ProcessEnd(element, context);
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you explain what the code must do, what the input or output is or any errors?

Comment: Hola H. Pauwelyn, the code receives <strong> tags and must convert them to <span> tags, and then obtain them in the: IList<IElement> elements = HtmlConverter.ConvertToElements(html, properties);